# capistrano doesn't call deploy:start when executing deploy:cold

Tags: capistrano

I'm using capistrano 2 to deploy my application. According to the documentation, the `deploy:cold` task will call `deploy:update` followed by `deploy:migrate` and finally call `deploy:start`.

In my application I don't have a migration step, and when I run `cap deploy:cold`, it does the update but then shows this:

```
* 2014-04-09 14:57:45 executing `deploy:migrate'
`deploy:migrate' is only run for servers matching {:roles=>:db, :only=>{:primary=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

and `deploy:start` is not being called. If I call it manually, it works fine - but never through `deploy:cold`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Capistrano 2 defines a default task called `deploy:migrate` that is specified to run only for the role `:db`. If you don't have that role in your application (which most do not), then when `deploy:migrate` runs it will error out on the missing role, and that kind of error normally terminates the deployment scenario.

This can happen for other tasks, if you have a complex setup where some tasks are only run for specific servers. This behavior is not documented at all at Capistrano's site, which is a shame.

Starting with Capistrano 2.7 there is a way to circumvent the "is only run for servers matching role" error, by specifying a task property that tells Capistrano to skip tasks if no servers matches any of its specified roles:

For example:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :stuff, :roles => :somerole, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
    # stuff
  end
end
```

Now this works well for custom tasks, but how to set this for the default task `migrate` ? you have to override the task with your own setting and add the `:on_no_matching_servers` option. I've added this to the `global.rb` file:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :migrate, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do end
end
```